# Error en WordPress por función each() deprecated

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin

Al poner PHP 8 Estoy teniendo un problema en la web debido a un error con la función each() obsoleta, en otras partes del código lo he podido solventar con un foreach pero en este caso no se como hacerlo para que no de el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function each()
```

El código que da conflicto es:

```
while (
  $activity = each( $this->element_activities[ $tag ] ) 
) {
  list( $method, $params ) = $activity[1];
  switch ( $method ) {
    case 'drop_param':
      WPBMap::dropParam(
        $params['name'], 
        $params['attribute_name']
      );
    break;
```

He intentado reemplazarlo por un foreach:

```
foreach (
  $this->element_activities[ $tag ] as $activity
) {
  list( $method, $params ) = $activity[1];
  switch ( $method ) {
```

Y me da el siguiente error, probando varias maneras no consigo que funcione:

```
Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported
```

Esto es un var_dump del array:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=> array(2) {
    [0]=> string(6) "modify"
    [1]=> array(3) {
      ["name"]=> string(6) "vc_row" 
      ["setting_name"]=> array(1) {
        ["params"]=> array(12) {
          [0]=> array(5) {
            ["type"]=> string(11) "colorpicker"
            ["heading"]=> string(23) "Custom Background Color"
            ["param_name"]=> string(8) "bg_color"
            ["description"]=> string(35) "Select backgound color for your row"
            ["edit_field_class"]=> string(8) "col-md-6"
          }
          [1]=> array(5)
```

¿Podéis echarme una mano con esto? Gracias.

Comment: El error que comentas no aparece en tu código. Se refiere a que en alguna parte que no vemos has puesto algo asi como `$variable{0}` cuando seguramente poniéndolo así se soluciona: `$variable[0]`.

Comment: @masterguru muchas gracias! estaba tan cegado con el foreach que no terminé de leer el error que indicaba la clase que tenía {}. Ahora ya no da error, aparecen warning pero funciona la web: Warning: Undefined array key 0 in .. Warning: Undefined array key 1 in .. esto en el foreach que he puesto

Comment: Pon el foreach entero, pues es probable que esos nuevos errores tengan relación con lo que acabas de arreglar y que seguimos sin ver (y a ciegas va a ser que no se te puede ayudar demasiado, claro)

Comment: si el problema está relacionado a un theme basado en WPBakery que ya no tiene soporte una solucion es comprar o adquirir un theme mas nuevo ( no necesariamente el mismo ) y en la carpeta `config/plugins` del bundle debería haber una versión actualizada del "plugin" js_composer ( backup de la carpeta y expande `js_composer.zip` en su lugar )